# Python: Messaging through redis channels, what's the proper way to wait for published responses to a specific query?

Tags: python, redis

Suppose I have another program running that listens to 'query_channel' and then publishes a response to 'response_channel' (just turning everything to uppercase).

My current working code looks like this:

```
import aioredis
import asyncio
import uuid

async def listen(pubsub, response_future, uuid):
    async for message in pubsub.listen():
        if uuid.upper() in str(message['data']):
            response_future.set_result(message)
            break

async def send_message():
    print('start')
    redis_host = 'localhost'
    redis_port = 6379
    query_channel = 'query_channel'
    response_channel = 'response_channel'

    redis_client = await aioredis.from_url(f'redis://{redis_host}:{redis_port}')
    response_future = asyncio.Future()
    message_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

    pubsub = redis_client.pubsub()
    await pubsub.subscribe(response_channel)
    listen_task = asyncio.create_task(listen(pubsub, response_future, message_id))

    message = f'Hello, Server! Request ID: {message_id}'
    await redis_client.publish(query_channel, message)

    response = await asyncio.gather(response_future, listen_task)

    await redis_client.close()
    print('done')
    return response

async def main():
    response = await send_message()
    print('Received response:', response)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Are there reasons why I should not use this kind of patterns? In particular I'm wondering if it will still work well when the channel starts to get crowded and therefore listen() getting a lot of messages that have unrelated message ids. Or are there even different preferable methods for achieving the same (sending something in a query channel, then waiting for a particular response in a response channel)?